# Find limit points of the set $\{x/(1+|x|) : x \in \mathbb R\}$.

Tags: real-analysis

> How to find limit points of the set
>   $$
> \bigg\{\frac{x}{1+|x|}: x \in \mathbb{R}\bigg\}\,\,\,?
> $$

Comment: What have you tried? The best approach is to draw a picture, "guess" the answer, then prove that it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given set $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}:\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}\right\}$, the limit points are the following:

$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \dfrac{x}{1+|x|} = \dfrac{x}{-x} = -1$

$\lim_{x\to\infty} \dfrac{x}{1+|x|} = \dfrac{x}{x} = 1$

$-1$ and $1$ are the limit points at the extreme. Now for all other $x\in \mathbb{R}$,

For $x>0, \dfrac{x}{1+|x|}=\dfrac{x}{1+x} < 1$ and

For $x<0$, let $x = -y, y >0 , \dfrac{x}{1+|x|}=\dfrac{-y}{1+y} < -1$

We will see that the limit is obtained just by substituting for $x$ in $\dfrac{x}{1+|x|}$. So the limit points for the non-extreme x are in $(-1,1)$.

Thus the set of limit points is $[-1,1]$

Comment: The set you have is exactly (-1,1) so the set of limit points is [-1,1].

Comment: Correct. I am sorry did not explicitly mention that.

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking  $[-1,1] $.  The reason(s):  you can replace  $\lvert x \rvert  $ by $x $ for $x \gt 0$,  and by $-x $ for  $x\lt 0$...  dividing by $x $ in either case and letting  $x\to \pm\infty  $ gives $\pm 1 $...  also note  $\lvert \frac x {1+\lvert x\rvert }\rvert \le 1$...   Note that at $x =0$ we have $0$, and the function is continuous...  so it should fill out the whole interval...